# I have a Binary Search Tree function with the search function but it needs to be recursive (within the "nodeList" class)

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I need to place the search function within the nodeList class. But whenever I do that, I can't call the function.

I also need to place the result check functionality with successful and unsuccessful print commands within the search function.

```
def search(node, value):
    if node == None:
        return None
    
    if node.value == value:
        return node

    if node.value > value:
        return search(node.left, value)
    else:
        return search(node.right, value)

# Sample node data
class nodeList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

# Create sample node
root = nodeList(10) 
root.left = nodeList(7) 
root.right = nodeList(15) 
root.left.left = nodeList(4) 
root.left.right = nodeList(9) 

# Call the search function
result = search(root, 15) 

if result != None: 
  print ("Node found with value: ", result.value)
else:
  print ("Search was unsuccessful")
```

It works fine as is but breaks when I place the search function in the class nodeList.

Comment: why do you "need" to put that function inside the class? What does the code look like when you do it, and how does it "break"?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```py
class nodeList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def search(self, value):
        if self.value == value:
            return self

        if self.value > value:
            return self.left.search(value) if self.left is not None else None
        else:
            return self.right.search(value) if self.right is not None else None
```

and it seemed to give expected result when calling `root.search(value)`.

I just moved the `None` check because it was throwing an exception in the case of unsuccessful search

The following piece of code gives the same result, but it includes the print statements:

```py
class nodeList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def search(self, value):
        if self.value == value:
            print("Node found with value: ", value)
            return

        if self.value > value:
            if self.left is not None:
                self.left.search(value)
                return
        else:
            if self.right is not None:
                self.right.search(value)
                return

        print("Search was unsuccessful for value: ", value)
```

Then:

```py
root = nodeList(10)
root.left = nodeList(7)
root.right = nodeList(15)
root.left.left = nodeList(4)
root.left.right = nodeList(9)

# Call the search function
root.search(5)
root.search(9)
root.search(10)
root.search(11)
root.search(15)
```

gives:

```
Search was unsuccessful for value:  5
Node found with value:  9
Node found with value:  10
Search was unsuccessful for value:  11
Node found with value:  15
```